# Can't get the parameter passed from view to controller in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am passing a value($model->stop) of my form to controller action(search2) via button click.But I can't get that value in the controller.

view:

```
<?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Search'), ['search2','id' => $model->stop], ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])
```

Controller:

```
  public function actionSearch2($id)
  {
      if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {   
        $searchModel   = new ScheduleRouteSearch();
        $dataProvider1 = $searchModel->search1(Yii::$app->request-   >queryParams, $id);

        return $this->render('search', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider1,
        ]);
      }
  }
```

Error:

```
    Bad Request (#400)
    Missing required parameters: id
    The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.
    Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.
```

Help me to solve this.

Comment: What type of variable is `$model->stop` and do you have any Url rules in UrlManager for this action?

Comment: $model->stop is an integer value.No url rules are defined.

Comment: Check if link is created properly. Then try to access this action with parameter manually from the browser's address bar.

Comment: Ok.Thank you Bizley.

Answer (score 2):

All your code seems right,
I think problem is with $model->stop value

```
$model->stop  // value might be null  --null value also gives missing parameter error
```

please check.